# how to pass connection object from one method into another method?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
import mysql.connector

class Database(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def establishingconnection(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def executequery(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def closingconnection(self):
        pass

class sqlDatabase(Database):

    def establishingconnection(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="Preethi@123",
            database="naveent"
        )
        if conn.is_connected()==True:
            print("Connected to Database")
        else:
            print("Unable to connect")
        print("----------------------------------------")
        return conn

    def executequery(conn):
        conn=conn.establishingconnection()
        mycursor=conn.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT*FROM studentinfo WHERE Address='Chittoor'")
        a=mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in a:
            print(x)
        print("-------------------------------------------")


    def closingconnection(conn):
        conn=conn.establishingconnection()
        conn.close()
        print("After using close")
        if not conn.is_connected()==True:
            print("connection is closed")


obj=sqlDatabase()
obj.establishingconnection()
obj.executequery()
obj.closingconnection()pe here
```

as u can see in the code, i have closed the connection to database by establishing connection again.
i know i am new to coding. but couldnt predict what i did wrong. from whatever i know, close syntax works like connectionobject.close(). but when i pass the conn in the method as parameter, close shows no attribute error. pls let me know what i do. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the argument to the method `executequery` wrong.
Since this is a class, you should pass the arguments in the class methods beginning with `self`, and then, accessing a attribute of the instanced object.

Like this:

```
class sqlDatabase(Database):
    def establishingconnection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="Preethi@123",
            database="naveent"
        )
        if self.conn.is_connected():
            print("Connected to Database")
        else:
            print("Unable to connect")
        print("----------------------------------------")

    def executequery(self):
        mycursor = self.conn.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE Address='Chittoor'")
        a = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in a:
            print(x)
        print("-------------------------------------------")

    def closingconnection(self):
        self.conn.close()
        print("After using close")
        if not self.conn.is_connected():
            print("Connection is closed")
```

Notice that what's changed is that, instead of passing `conn` variable directly (Which is not correct because this is a class attribute), we instead passed the "self object" and acccessed it's attribute "conn" right after, doing `mycursor = self.conn.cursor()` instead of `conn=conn.establishingconnection()`.